# Android 9 app menu is dark text on dark background

Tags: android, text, menu

I noticed, and users have reported,  that for Android 9 (API 28) my application's menu started showing the rather unreadable condition of dark text on a dark background:

[image: Android 9 app menu]

All other app versions show the correct light text on dark background.  This is the Android 8 (API 26) display:

[image: Android 8 app menu]

I tried setting the device theme from the Settings > Display > Advanced option available from the Android 9 settings, but the same condition occurs regardless of this setting.  I also did an app uninstall between tests with the same result.  Testing has been done using emulators.

Build specifics:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion  14
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 I'm wondering if there's a non-black-box solution, too. E. g. how to explicitly set the menu text in your app's theme to a system color that resolves to light in Android 9.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best approach is to use Theme.AppCompat and extend from AppCompatActivity.

In values/themes.xml:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:typeface">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and in my Activity class:

```
public class SimpleMetronome extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

The menu text color is now correct for the Pie and older versions.

Comment: May be too late, but what about setting `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
` in your theme?

Comment: Thank you, Caleb.  I ended up going with the Theme.AppCompat.  I'm OK with having to migrate portions to the compatibility  libraries, but it did double the size of my app (from about 0.6 MB to 1.5 MB).

Answer (score 0):

I had AppBarLayout with android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay" in my activity_main.xml.

So i just added following lines to night\themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```